# "Not a Group by Expression" Oracle SQL Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, count, case

I am trying to run the below code but I keep getting the `Not a Group by Expression` error. I did do some research and found I need to add the "Group By" which I did but I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

The end result I am looking for a list of `medicaid_no` and a `1` in the `test_flag` if they have a count of `more > 0` and the `In_Op` is equal to `inpatient`.

If you see below row 1,2, and 4 meet the criteria `count > 0` and have `Inpatient` while the others don't, so they get a `0`.

```
Row MEDICAID_NO TEST_FLAG
1   999999         1
2   1111111        1
3   3333333        0
4   444444         1
5   88888888       0
```

Heres my code

```
SELECT medicaid_no, count(*)
,(CASE WHEN count(*)>0 and In_Op IN('Inpatient')
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_FLAG
FROM top_member_claims 
GROUP BY medicaid_no
```

Comment: Sorry, but your example data does not include Inpatient column.

Comment: The column is in another CTE called top_member_claims

Comment: `count(*)` is always > 0, so testing it has no real meaning...

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's a column called `In_Op` in `top_member_claims` table, and should be in

the `Group By` Expression as `Group By medicaid_no, In_Op`.

So, use :

```
CREATE TABLE top_member_claims
(
  row_   int,
  MEDICAID_NO    int,
  TEST_FLAG int,
  In_Op varchar2(50)
);

INSERT INTO top_member_claims VALUES (1, 999999, 1, 'Inpatient');

SELECT medicaid_no, count(*),
      (CASE WHEN count(*)>0 and In_Op IN('Inpatient')
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END) AS test_FLAG
 FROM top_member_claims 
GROUP BY medicaid_no, In_Op;

MEDICAID_NO COUNT(*)    TEST_FLAG
  999999       1            1
  3333333      1            1
  1111111      1            0
  444444       1            0
  88888888     1            1
```

But do not use

```
SELECT medicaid_no, count(*),
      (CASE WHEN count(*)>0 and In_Op IN('Inpatient')
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END) AS test_FLAG
 FROM top_member_claims 
GROUP BY medicaid_no; -- yields below

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9dd7d9/1)